# My iPhone 7 Plus died after being exposed to cold weather and a bit of rain. Will I be able to retrieve my data?

Tags: iphone, battery, data-recovery

My iPhone 7 Plus won't respond to a hard reset. I'm not able to switch it on either. The phone detects the Home button being pressed only sometimes. I haven't backed up my data in a long time and really want it back, even if the phone dies out.

Here's how it died out:

My phone was out for a long time when the temperature was around 5-6 degree Celsius. It was dewy and there was some drizzle as well. When I was clicking a picture, the screen showed red and white vertical lines. It flickered once and the phone died out.

After about 4-5 hours, I checked it again. The screen showed a faint blue light but nothing else was working. When I put it to charge, the phone did vibrate. But even after charging it for 4-5 hours, it didn't work. After a few hours, the screen showed two white horizontal stripes and then it died down completely.

Now, there is no light on the screen. The phone doesn't vibrate when I put it for charging either.

What do you think the problem is? How should I retrieve my data?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How does the iPhone respond when pressing Home button? Does it give a haptic feedback (vibration)? Did you try connecting the phone to a computer?

Comment: Yes, it gives haptic feedback but only sometimes. I just checked it again - it didn't respond. It was responding absolutely fine until a minute ago. Yes, I tried connecting it but my laptop doesn't detect it.

Comment: I'm afraid but I think if a computer if not detecting it, your only resort would be to take it to an authorized technician who can attempt data recovery. You can attempt by trying on a different computer/using different cable or by attempting when the home button is responding.

Comment: Damn, what do you reckon is the problem here? Is it the motherboard?